# How to avoid duplicates generated from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have  a for each loop on my xslt file, which will go and process multiple Conditions, If any of the conditions have a matching scenario than I want to exit out of the loop and give the first value(which has satisfied the condition) for my output.

Here is my xml file

```
     <Product>
     <ContactDetails>
     <addressdetail>
     <Street>Stack</Street>
     <HouseNumber>123</HouseNumber>
     </addressdetail>
     <addressdetail>
     <Street>Stack</Street>
     <HouseNumber>123456</HouseNumber>
     </addressdetail>
     <addressdetail>
     <Street>Stack</Street>
     <HouseNumber>456</HouseNumber>
     </addressdetail>
     </ContactDetails>
     </Product>
```

and in my XSL file i have some kinding like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"                 version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"                 xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">     
        <p1:product_req>
         <p2:Contactdetails_Req>
        <xsl:for-each select ="Product[ContactDetails= 'addressdetails']  ">
            <xsl:if test="Street='Stack'" >
            <p3:SC>abc</p3:SC>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
         </p2:Contactdetails_Req> 
     </p1:product_req>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After the transformation, I am having three values on my output xml

```
          <p1:Product_Req>
            <p2:ContactDetails_Req>   
            <p3:ac>abc</p3:ac>
            <p3:ac>abc</p3:ac>
            <p3:ac>abc</p3:ac>
            </p1:Product_Req>
            </p2:ContactDetails_Req>
```

But I dont need the repeting values on my output xml, I only need one value on my Xml node ac. I have tried using the identity transform but nothing seems like working, any help is highly appreciated

```
<p1:Product_Req>
<p2:ContactDetails_Req>    
<p3:ac>abc</p3:ac>
</p1:Product_Req>
</p2:ContactDetails_Req>
```

I need to get my transformed output without any duplicates.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Your code does **not** provide the output you claim.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. If - as it seems -  you want to test if at least one address (in the entire XML) has the given street, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:if test="Product/ContactDetails/addressdetail/Street='Stack'" >
            <!-- whatever you want to output goes here -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hello Michael, I appreciate your help. I  am still getting multiple values on my xml node .Can you suggest is there any way i can avoid multiple values out of my transform, I need to Run a loop on contact details, for each address detail until i get a matching condition,assign the value and exit the loop if it satisfy's my conditon

Comment: @JordanBelfort I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying. I suggest you edit your question and clarify more - and esp. post the expected result.